# Switch right of TextInputLayout Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, switch-statement

I would like to place a Switch right of a TextInputLayout, with match_parent parameters on the TextInput and a margin.

Placing the switch to the left seems to work, however it is hidden when placing it to the right.

See the two images below:

[image: Switch to the left]

[image: Switch to the right]

As you can see the switch places itself wrongly.

Here is my XML code. The main layout is a CoordinatorLayout:

```
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Social Networks"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/myprofile_google"
                                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_grey_800"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Google +" />

                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <Switch
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>



                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `layout_width` of your `TextInputLayout` to `0dp`, and add this attribute to it as well:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

What's happening right now is that your TextInputLayout has a width of `match_parent`. What this will do is fill the entire *remaining* space of the parent (this is somewhat unique to LinearLayout). When your `Switch` is on the left, it gets enough space for it and then the TextInputLayout takes up the rest. However, when the Switch is on the right, the TextInputLayout takes up all the space first!

Using weight instead will make sure that *other* components get the space they need *before* the weighted component gets the extra space.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two bits in your XML. 
Firstly, the orientation on your linear layout containing both your input layout and switch. Secondly, use weighting to show both items as you've specified that the text input layout should match the parent (fill the view width in this case).

This layout produces your desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Social Networks"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/myprofile_google"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Google +" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, or even better redo the whole layout in a ConstraintLayout.

The RelativeLayout implementation would probably be something like this

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/switch"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/myprofile_google"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue_grey_800"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Google +" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>



                </LinearLayout>
```